# For each vector of the cell A, How to find all possible combinations of its components that are not contained in vectors of the cell B?

Tags: matlab, combinations, cell-array

For each vector of the cell `A`, How to find all possible combinations of its components that are not contained in vectors of the cell `B`?

```
   A = {[2 3 6 21],[66 4 2 7],[84 56 66 47 45]};
   B = {[5 6 9 20 21],[7 85 14 2 3],[5 66 84 10 23 35 56],[5 6 87 14 21 29]};
```

For `A{1}`, all possible combinations which satisfy the condition:

```
{[2 6],[2 21],[3 6],[3 21],[2 6 21],[2 3 6],[2 3 21],[3 6 21],[2 3 6 21]}
```

`[2 3]` is contained in `B{2}`

`[6 21]` is contained in `B{1}`

Comment: What do you mean by 'all possible combinations'?

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior: all possible combinations without repetition, and if 'a' is a sub-vector of any vector of the cell A, it should not be contained in any vector from B. I want to find all sub-vectors 'a'.

Comment: so for A{1}, there's only 3, right?

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior: for A{1}, there is 9

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
C = cell(1, numel(A));
for ii = 1:numel(A)
    aux = arrayfun(@(x) num2cell(nchoosek(A{ii}, x), 2)', 1:numel(A{ii}), 'Un', 0);
    aux = [aux{:}];
    C{ii} = aux(~cellfun(@(a) any(cellfun(@(b) all(ismember(a, b)), B)), aux));
end
```

The result will be in `C`. Run `celldisp(C{1})` to see the result for `A{1}`, for example.

This code takes every vector in `A` and find all possible combinations using [nchoosek](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html). Then, it checks if any combination has all values contained on any vector of `B`, returning the remaining combinations which are ont in `B` and putting them into `C`.

Comment: is there other way to find the result, because for a large vector : ??? Error using ==> vertcat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Comment: What size are your vectors? Sure there are other ways. You could try tweaking my answer, or change the `arrayfun` and `cellfun` to loops.